# How to change google cloud platform account from company to personal, or how to delete company account created by mistake?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I already have a google cloud platform account from my personal mail.

As I just joined a new company, I got a google mail account and thought I could use it to create another google cloud platform account (for creating projects and using some google APIs).

I don't remember how I created this new account or if I selected *"company"* or *"individual"*, but I suspect I selected *"company"*. Now, google asks me to verify the *"organisation"* with the company domain! I won't do this obviously, so I am wondering how I can switch it to *"individual"*! How to do this?

My other idea is to delete and create back.

I have tried to delete the account using [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554?hl=en) (delete your organization's google account).

I have been able to remove my personal billing account, delete the automatically created project but I cannot do the step 6: completely closing the account (so I can repurpose it to create an *"individual"* account instead)! Step 6 did not work because I could not sign in to the admin account.

Any help would be super appreciated I am banging my head for 2 hours for this since this morning!

Comment: This is even getting funnier now!
I was going to file a support case but I need to create a project for that. And obvioulsy I cannot create a project but that requires verifying the organisation which I cannot do xD

Comment: If you got a google account from your company, that account administrator is different. Contact them!

Answer (score 0):

Account you've been assigned probably belongs to a [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com/) or [Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity).
As suggested in the comment, you should contact your Organization Administrator.
You can look for that role on the [IAM page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/iam).